# How to find the $\pi$?

Tags: proof-explanation, circles, pi

We know as we increase the number of sides in regular polygon, after infinite repetition it will give us a circle. So, is there any way to find a function which approaches to value of $\pi$ when we consider  $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}$?

Comment: There are a lot of such functions. Do you seek one in general or one that uses your polygon approach?

Answer (score 3):

The area of a regular $n$-gon circumscribed by the circle of radius $r$ is 
$$A_n = \frac{1}{2}nr^2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right).$$ You can get the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712375/perimeter-and-area-of-a-regular-n-gon). Taking limit, we will get circle when $n\to\infty$. We can use this formula for $\pi$, $$\pi=\frac{\text{Area of circle with radius r}}{\text{radius}^2}=\frac{1}{r^2}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right).$$

Using this result you can tend to $\pi$ putting bigger and bigger values of $n$ in $\frac{n}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qcmnk1sl0e) I have plotted $\pi -\frac{x}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{x}\right)$, for first few values of $x$ very fast, then slowly approaches $0$, means $\frac{n}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\to\pi$ very slowly but, the methods explained in the given [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189820/calculating-pi-manually) in comments tend $\pi$ much faster than this.